# Is the "review" area really worth the trouble to 'review' the items?

Tags: discussion, answers, review

Is it just me or does the 'review' page have too much dross for the metal looked for?

I've reviewed probably well in excess of a thousand items but I've NEVER come across even one item that even remotely comes *across* as an item that needs to be flagged.

Does the algorithm need tweaking or is it just as good as it gets.  If it won't or can't get any better at getting items that do need to be flagged, how about some incentives to users that slog through the good and reasonable answers to find these unicorns of bad answers?

Comment: A fair bit of the junk was removed when review was introduced and a lot of users (like me) went on reviewing tears. I never flagged much before then, but shot up to flag weight of 500 before Deputy was introduced. Today, I rarely visit review, precisely because there's less garbage to see. However, over a thousand items... you probably should've been able to find at least one flaggable thing.

Answer (score 13):

If your flag rate on `/review` is less than 1%, your low quality threshold is far too low. The low quality posts, first answers and late answers lists have at least one “not an answer” post on most pages of 30. Late answers are where most of the spam happens, too; it's important to detect that.

`/review` also isn't just about flagging, there are a number of other things you can do to make the site better:

- **Upvote** those posts that are actually good! This is particularly important with regards to new users, to help them earn the rep to participate in the site's other features.
- **Comment** on mediocre posts and let the author how they could be improved (especially answers with just a link — cite the [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) page).
- **Edit** low-quality posts that *are* salvageable (many new users aren't familiar with formatting, and merely getting the code blocks to show correctly is a major improvement). Giving questions clear, non-generic titles is also extremely beneficial to the site as a whole.
- **Vote to close** irredeemable or off-topic questions (more common amongst new users), or flag them if you don't have the vote-to-close privilege.

Comment: +1, hope you don't mind my tweaks

Comment: Exactly!  /review isn't just for bad things!  Look at the first posts by news users - see something great, upvote it as a way to welcome that user to the site.

Comment: we should probably put this guidance in the sidebar of that page, yes?

Comment: ok great! a TL;DR version of this is in the /review sidebar, feel free to suggest further copyedits.

Comment: +1 Never thought about using it to give upvotes, but I will now!

Comment: @Jeff Great! How attached are you to having the same text in all tabs? “Voting to close off-topic questions, or flagging them.” appears even in the answer-only tabs. “Flagging non-answers”? “Flagging posts that do not belong here”?